# Validar data de nascimento, para que não possa registrar menores de 18 anos (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, validação, data

Tenho um campo chamado 'txtdata_nasc' do tipo date. Preciso que o usuário não possa digitar uma data que faça-o ter menos de 18 anos de idade, mas também que não possa ter uma idade absurda, como por exemplo 100 anos de idade, preciso que ele possa digitar no máximo uma data de nascimento que o faça ter 60 anos de idade. Por exemplo, ele não pode digitar(usando o exemplo de hoje, 05/05/2018) uma data maior que '05/05/2000' e uma data menor que 05/05/1958.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma solução simples para validar se a pessoa tem mais ou menos de 18 anos é criar uma data com mesmo mês e dia, e com o ano somado de 18. Depois apenas precisa de comparar se essa data é menor ou maior que a data corrente.

Exemplo:

```js
const inputNasc = document.getElementById("txtdata_nasc");

document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function(){
  //obter array com [ano,mes,dia] através de split("-") e convertendo em numero com Map
  let nasc = inputNasc.value.split("-").map(Number);
  //construir data 18 anos a seguir a data dada pelo usuario
  let depois18Anos = new Date(nasc[0] + 18, nasc[1] - 1, nasc[2]);
  let agora = new Date();
  
  if (depois18Anos <= agora){
    console.log("Maior de 18");
  }
  else {
    console.log("Menor de 18");
  }
  event.preventDefault(); //só para não mudar de pagina na submissão do formulario
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="date" id="txtdata_nasc">
  <input type="submit" value="Validar">
</form>
```

É importante de referir que como os meses em Javascript começam em zero, a parte do mês tem de ser subtraída de 1 com `nasc[1] - 1`.

Para validar para menor que `100` anos pode utilizar exatamente o mesmo principio, mudando apenas na comparação:

```
let nasc = inputNasc.value.split("-").map(Number);
let depois18Anos = new Date(nasc[0] + 18, nasc[1] - 1, nasc[2]);
let depois100Anos = new Date(nasc[0] + 100, nasc[1] - 1, nasc[2]);
let agora = new Date();

if (depois18Anos > agora){
  console.log("Menor de 18");
}
else if(depois100Anos < agora){
  console.log("Maior de 100");
}
else {
  console.log("valido");
}
```

Com [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) consegue tornar mais simples e clara a construção das datas X anos à frente:

```
let [ano, mes, dia] = inputNasc.value.split("-").map(Number);
//    ^----^----^--- Destructuring assignment
let depois18Anos = new Date(ano + 18, mes - 1, dia);
let depois100Anos = new Date(ano + 100, mes - 1, dia);
```

Comment: Tem como você me ajudar no meu Trabalho de Conclusão de Curso(TCC)? Eu estou trabalhando com o JavaScript, mas estou tendo muitas dificuldades.

Comment: @PedroVinicius Nem por isso pois não é o objetivo do site. Aqui o objetivo é esclarecer duvidas especificas que tem no escopo de programação, e nesse sentido terei todo o gosto em ajudar.

Comment: Eu sei que não é o objetivo do site, foi só uma pergunta.

Comment: Eu gostaria de saber como que eu faço agora para usar este código no meu Site. Devo criar uma function?

Comment: Eu tenho uma página de cadastro, onde há um botão "cadastrar" no final, que executa todas as validações, e tem o método onclick="return validacaodenome();" que é a function que eu uso para validar todo o resto do site.

Comment: Tem como eu colocar esse seu código para retornar no meu botão de cadastro?

Comment: Desculpa pela pergunta, eu realmente tenho dificuldade em JS, pois eu tive de aprender tudo pela Internet para realizar meu TCC. E como tu sabes, na Internet não há muita coisa sobre JavaScript que me ajude.

Comment: Todas essas questões que fez devem ser novas perguntas, assumindo que já não existem perguntas iguais no site que respondam exatamente ao que pretende. Logo a primeira coisa a fazer é procurar por questões idênticas e caso não encontre faça uma nova.